# Assembly must be registered in isolation error

Tags: plugins, workflow-foundation-4, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow-activity

I'm trying to load a custom workflow activity onto a crm server.  I loaded the project onto the server and have been using the CRM Plug-in Registration Tool.  The server is CRM2011 and thus supports .NET 4.0 activities.  However, when I press the "Register" button (After the assembly has successfully loaded onto the Tool) the following error occurs:

```
`Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException'1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Action failed for assembly 'ExecuteSQLJob, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=914788311ab3af7d': **Assembly must be registered in isolation**.
Detail: <OrganizationServiceFault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220906</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>Action failed for assembly 'ExecuteSQLJob, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=914788311ab3af7d': Assembly must be registered in isolation.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2012-06-21T19:50:30.5216535Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault>
    <ErrorCode>-2147220906</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Message>Action failed for assembly 'ExecuteSQLJob, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=914788311ab3af7d': Assembly must be registered in isolation.</Message>
    <Timestamp>2012-06-21T19:50:30.5216535Z</Timestamp>
    <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
    <TraceText i:nil="true" />
  </InnerFault>
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>`

`Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)`

`Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService.Create(Entity entity)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy.CreateCore(Entity entity)
   at PluginRegistrationTool.RegistrationHelper.RegisterAssembly(CrmOrganization org, String pathToAssembly, CrmPluginAssembly assembly) in C:\hbs\apps\prod\hbs\downloads\crm2011\crm2011_MicrosoftDynamicsCRM2011SDK\sdk\tools\pluginregistration\RegistrationHelper.cs:line 227
   at PluginRegistrationTool.PluginRegistrationForm.btnRegister_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\hbs\apps\prod\hbs\downloads\crm2011\crm2011_MicrosoftDynamicsCRM2011SDK\sdk\tools\pluginregistration\PluginRegistrationForm.cs:line 452`
```

What does registering in isolation mean?  Is it simply a matter of where the assembly is saved on the server or is it more complicated?

I've been following MSDN's tutorial's so far but can't find an explanation for this.

Thanks!

Comment: After loading the Assembly check the "Sandbox" option, that's all

Comment: But what if he doesn't want to run in sandbox mode? Do you have the requisite permissions to register plugins? I would check that first.

Comment: @Anwar that is not a best solution, the best solution is by Paul Way, assign a new deployment manager

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you aren't a Deployment Administrator then you will need to register it in isolation mode.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2011/08/17/error-message-assembly-must-be-registered-in-isolation-when-registering-plugins-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx

[image: Add User as Deployment Manager]

Comment: Thanks, I'll find out who the Deployment Admin is at my office and try it.

Comment: Is this the case even if I'm a Sys Admin?