# crm plugin smtpclient=new smtpclient() get Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission

Tags: c#, email, dynamic, plugins, crm

I am trying to create a plugin to send email via SMTP. I get an exception when the code gets to the `SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(sever);` line. The exception is:

> Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

I have tested SMTP sending email and it works fine.
The testing code is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string server = "smtp.mail.ex.com";
    string to = "ex@ex.com";
    string from = "donotreply@ex.com";
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
    message.Subject = "Using the new SMTP client.";
    message.Body = @"Using this new feature, you can send an e-mail message from an application very easily.";
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false ;

    try
    {
        client.Send(message);
        MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateTestMessage2(): {0}",
                    ex.ToString());
    } 
}
```

This one runs fine and I can receive the email. Why does it have the security request when it runs in CRM plugin?

Comment: a plugin for what? reading your tags maybe is for a crm platform: which one?

Comment: A MS Dynamics CRM plugin.

Comment: See if [`trust level` applies when using a port _other_ than `25`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alvar/archive/2010/02/08/smtp-problems-when-asp-net-is-not-running-in-full-trust.aspx) when connecting (can't tell in above code, so check `config` if using some custom port to connect to smtp server)

Comment: In the plugin, it cannot even create a new smtp client.

Answer (score 0):

There's a reasonable chance that your running up against the CRM sandbox behaviour.

> In this isolated environment, also known as a sandbox, a plug-in or
>   custom activity can make use of the full power of the Microsoft
>   Dynamics CRM SDK to access the organization web service. **Access to
>   the file system, system event log, certain network protocols,
>   registry, and more is prevented in the sandbox**.

If you are running on-premise you could try registering your plugin outside the sandbox (an option in the plugin registration tool).

Failing that you could just create an email record in CRM, and use the out of the box behaviour to send the email.

[Plug-in isolation, trusts, and statistics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg334752.aspx)

Comment: Hi James, I cannot register the plugin into none. It gives me an error message like this: "Assembly must be registered in isolation". Do you know why?

Comment: @HuLydia, you probably need to be a deployment administrator, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145900/assembly-must-be-registered-in-isolation-error

Answer (score 0):

Hu Lydia, May be what you can do in this case is to move the code to send the email to a web service and then call that web service from your plugin which should work even if the plugin is registered in sandbox. Hope that makes sense.